# Tables not appearing, I see commas instead

Tags: tables

I was trying to make a minimal working example but I struggle to reproduce this behaviour. I hope that some of you encountered my same problem and was able to identify the source of it.

Basically, SOME of my tables are not appearing in the pdf generated, instead I see some commas, like this:
[image]

Is this ever happened to one of you?

This is my preamble, the tables are coming from separate files where I am writing my chapters

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}

% paragraph spacing and indentation
\setlength\parindent{0cm}
\setlength\parskip{11pt}

% Remove asymmetric to swap margins
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, asymmetric]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}            
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,textfont=up]{caption}

% links
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}      
\definecolor{hyperlinkcolor}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29} % arsenic
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkbordercolor=lightgray,
    linkcolor=hyperlinkcolor,        % color of internal links
    citecolor=hyperlinkcolor,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=hyperlinkcolor,     % color of file links
    urlcolor=hyperlinkcolor       
}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\normalfont \sffamily \itshape \small}

%Algorithms
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

% Tables
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs} % toprule, ...
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain} % No headers in front matter

%\input{frontmatter/titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\normalfont 
\cleardoublepage



\setcounter{page}{1}  % TOC is page 1
{ % index
    \setlength\parskip{0pt}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
        linkcolor=black,        % color of internal links   
    }
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
}


\cleardoublepage

%\input{frontmatter/summary}
%\input{frontmatter/aknowledgments}

\clearpage

\mainmatter

% Headers
\fancyfoot{} % Remove the number of the page at the bottom
\pagestyle{fancy}\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}        
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}    

\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}    
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}     
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt} 

%\input{chapters/c1}
%\input{chapters/c2}
%\input{chapters/c2}
%\input{chapters/c3} % dummy titles...
%\input{chapters/results}

\cleardoublepage
% ---- Bibliography ----
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
%\bibliography{references}
%\nocite{*}

\appendix
\pagestyle{plain} 
%\input{appendices/app1}





\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your document example include  files unknown to us. Consequently we cant test it. Please replace remove those files and from one insert table direct into your code example. Also instead `\input{<file name>}` is better to use `\include{<file name>}`.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the behaviour, if I just put a couple of tables instead of the "input" commands where I read the contents it works perfectly. I was hoping that the same thing happened to someone else or that from the preamble you were able to spot something strange. Now I commented out the input commands in the example I put.

Comment: you should be able to make a small example that demonstrates the problem. Start with a copy of the document and delete everything that you can delete while still showing one set of commas.  Then delete everything from the preamble not used in the remaining small document and post the resulting document.

Comment: This does remind me of a recent question here, but I could not find it. Sorry. That was fixed by updating a package, if I recall.

Comment: \renewcommand{\captionfont}{\normalfont \sffamily \itshape \small} this command was the problem, I removed it and it works smoothly

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments

Comment: More like because there's no MWE and other people except the OP cannot answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

- Sorry, your document example doesn't contain information which can confirm your claims (it doesn't contain any table)
- I really doubt that this can happen, if you obey LaTeX document coding rules.
- Your document preamble is a bit unusual:

  - `hyperref` package and its settings should be (with rare exception, which I didn't see in your document example) loaded last in the preamble
  - all definitions of new commands, page styles etc. should be in preamble. Document body should contain only document content with necessary markup instructions.
  - don't use obsolete packages as is `subfigure`. Instead it are now available `subfig` and `subcaption` with a bit different syntax: `\subfigure` --> `subfloat` at `subfig`, and

```
      \begin{subfigure}[<position>]{<width>} 
      \includegraphics[...]{...}
      \caption{...}
      \label{...}
      \end{subfigure}
```

at `subcaption`.

- I suspect that your error is caused by your table construction. That I (or anyone) can confirm this, you should show table code, which disappear. A small table, used in the MWE below, this cannot happen.

Below is a suggestion how your preamble can be reorganized and with example of document body which works fine:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
% Remove asymmetric to swap margins
\usepackage[vmargin={2cm, 4cm}, 
            hmargin=3cm, 
            asymmetric      % due to equal left and right text border is not needed
            ]{geometry}
% paragraph spacing and indentation
\setlength\parindent{0cm}
\setlength\parskip{11pt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum} % added for dummy text

%Algorithms
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

% Tables
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs} % toprule, ...
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfigure}  % it is obsolete, use
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

% Headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot{} % Remove the number of the page at the bottom
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}

\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}

\usepackage[font={small,sf}, labelfont=bf]{caption}

% links
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{hyperlinkcolor}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29} % arsenic
\hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,    % false: boxed links; true: colored links
        linkcolor=black,    % color of internal links
    colorlinks=true,        % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkbordercolor=lightgray,
    linkcolor=hyperlinkcolor,   % color of internal links
    citecolor=hyperlinkcolor,   % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=hyperlinkcolor,   % color of file links
    urlcolor=hyperlinkcolor
}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain} % No headers in front matter
%\input{frontmatter/titlepage}

\thispagestyle{empty}
%\normalfont        % <--- not needed
\cleardoublepage

\setcounter{page}{1}  % TOC is page 1

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

%\cleardoublepage   % <--- not needed

%\input{frontmatter/summary}
%\input{frontmatter/aknowledgments}

%\clearpage         % <--- not needed

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}

%%%% FOR TEST PURPOSES ONLY
\chapter{Does table really disappear?}
\lipsum
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{My table not disaper from document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 &   2   &   3   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%%%%
%\input{chapters/c1}
%\input{chapters/c2}
%\input{chapters/c2}
%\input{chapters/c3} % dummy titles...
%\input{chapters/results}

\cleardoublepage

\appendix
\pagestyle{plain}   % <--???
%\input{appendices/app1}

\backmatter
% ---- Bibliography ----
\pagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
%\bibliography{references}
%\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

After two compiling it gets:

Content:
[image]

LoT:
[image]

Table in document:
[image]

**Conclusion:**
Above is not really an answer. More collected some tips, how you should organize your document.

To help you at "dissapearing" of table, you should in form of my MWE prepare your MWE, which reproduce your problem. Meaning in it replace my table with your troublemaker table. If it will works fine, than you have something strange in your document files. What, is from provided information not possible to figured-out. Sorry ...